# How can I intercept a function call to a .dll in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Our C++ application runs on Windows and consists of `Program.exe` which calls `Library.dll`.

Inside `Library.dll` the following method is implemented:

```
double SomeClass::getMeasurement() {...}
```

It is declared this way:

```
 class SomeClass {
    public:
    __declspec(dllexport) double getMeasurement(); 
 };
```

Inside `Program.exe` the method above is called once every second and the result is written to file.
However the output is not flushed.

Now a customer with an old version of the software (the signature of the method has not changed) suddenly needs to monitor the measurement value in real time.

Is there some way I can create a library: `Spy.dll` with just one method:

```
double SomeClass::getMeasurement() {
    double value;
    // get the value from Library.dll SomeClass::getMeasurement() somehow
    std::string message =  std::string("measurement: ") + std::to_string(value);
    OutputDebugStringA(msg.c_str());
    return value;  
}
```

and get Windows to load symbols from this .dll before the `Library.dll`?

Comment: There are several ways to get this done. Depends on the exact situation which is best. Is the function exported or is it a virtual method?

Comment: @CherryDT: it is exported `__declspec(dllexport)`.